# make page wait for the to be read from cache before loading up

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, async-await, local-storage

I have js function which is called in header section of my page. This Js function basically calls an API with async ajax and when it have the result back it caches the data in local storage(Reason calling the api in header is to save some time when page loads). In body (which is an angular app)of my html page I am suppose to read the returned value of API and construct page DOM. Issue is that sometime the value is not in cache yet (API returning later) and I am not sure how to make reading the value from local storage wait until there is a value there. Any suggestion as how I can make this work? Probably I need to change reading from local storage to some sort of promise which I don't know how.

Here is what I have in header:

```
<script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhttp.open("GET", "/api/orgData", true);
    this.xhttps.send();

getOrgData();

async function getOrgData() {
    var x = await resolveAfterOrgResponse();
    localStorage.setItem('OrgData', (x));
    console.log(x); 
}

function resolveAfterOrgResponse() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
                    resolve(xhttps.responseText);
                }
            };
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the body of the app, this is what I have:

```
config = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('orgData'));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this question have to do with Angular?

Comment: the body part where page is loading is in angular

Comment: Why is `getOrgData()` defined twice and `resolveAfterOrgResponse()` not defined?

Comment: There's simply not enough code here.  For example, where's the rest of the xhttpshell request code?  Why two copies of `getOrgData()` and no code for `resolveAfterOrgResponse()`?

Comment: I am sorry this was a mistake from me, I will update it now

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I updated the question, would appreciate any guidance, thanks